# Lazarus OnKeyPress on OS X

Tags: macos, lazarus, onkeypress

I'm using Lazarus 1.2.6 on OS X Yosemite, and my problem is, tha when I disabled `TabStop` in every object, and I wrote a pretty little code for that myself( because of need of circular tab-ing) , but using #9(tab) it won't work. Does work with any other key.

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: char);
begin
  if Key = #9 then
  form1.ActiveControl:=button4;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the fact that `OnKeyPress` only handles printable ASCII chars. In order to handle non-printable symbols like the tabulator key you should use the `OnKeyDown` event.

Your handler could look like:

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_TAB then
  form1.ActiveControl := button4;
end;
```

In order to access `VK_TAB` you should add `LCLType` to your uses clause. Of course this procedure should be defined as the handler of the `OnKeyDown` event of your controls or your form.

See http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/LCL_Key_Handling and http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/lcltype/index-2.html for reference.